# Do VBOs boost performance even when all data changes frequently

Tags: opengl

I'm doing a 2D turn based RTS game with 32x32 tiles (400-500 tiles per frame). I could use a VBO for this, but I may have to change almost all the VBO data each frame, as the background is a scrolling one and the visible tiles will change every time the map scrolls. Will using VBOs rather than client side vertex arrays still yield a performance benefit here? Also if using VBOs which data format is most efficient (float, or int16, or ...)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are simply scrolling, you can use the vertex shader to manipulate the position rather than update the vertices themselves. Pass in a 'scroll' value as a uniform to your background and simply add that value to the `x` (or `y`, or whatever applies to your case) value of each vertex.

Update:

If you intend to modify the VBO often, you can tell the driver this using the `usage` param of `glBufferData`. This page has a good description of how that works: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object, under Accessing VBOs. In your case, it looks like you should specify `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` to `glBufferData` so that the driver puts your VBO in the best place in memory for your application.

Comment: I cant do this as the tiles visible change every time the map scrolls. New tiles are added above and old ones are no longer rendered

Comment: I could do this but I suppose the driver has to upload data every frame in this case, and I'm wondering whether there will be any performance benefit over client side arrays for this reason

Comment: @Sudarshan S: Most likely, your driver will emulate exactly the dynamic VBO path, except you have a little less control.

Comment: @Sudarshan It may not be faster, but I'm sure it won't be slower. So why not just let the driver decide what's best for you, only telling him what he need's to know (using the usage hint).

Comment: You can send all the vertices each frame to the GPU, without using VBOs, or just update the relevant ones when you want to using a VBO and `glBufferSubData`. Either way you have to send some data each frame since things are changing, but if you use the VBO at least you can let the driver know you will be doing this through `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` and then it has a chance to optimize this.

Comment: @Christian:What mode must I use (GL_STREAM_DRAW or GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW), and what data type should I use for best performance?

Comment: @Sudarshan, if you are only going to use the data you send the GPU once per frame, GL_STREAM_DRAW. If you are going to potential re-use some or all of it, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.

Comment: As per the article I linked:

STREAM : You will modify the data once, then use it once, and repeat this process many times.

DYNAMIC : You will specify or modify the data repeatedly, and use it repeatedly after each time you do this.

Comment: @Sudarshan The data type? surely the one you use for non-VBO arrays. The VBO doesn't care about the data type, it's just a chunk of raw memory, where your vertex arrays (that have a certain type) are stored at. About the usage I'm not that sure (between you two suggestions), if not the whole buffer changes every frame (which would be a good idea in your case), then `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` should be the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

The regular approach is to move the camera and perform culling instead of updating the content of the VBOs. For a 2d game culling will use simple rectangle intersection algorithm, which you will need anyway for unit selection in the game. As a bonus, manipulating the camera will allow to rate the camera and zoom in and zoom out. Also you could combine several tiles (4, 9 or 16) into one VBO.

I would strongly advise against writing logic to move the tiles instead of the camera. It will take you longer, have more bugs, and be less flexible.

The format will depend on what data you are storing in the VBOs. When in doubt, just use uint8 for color and float32 for everything else. Though for a 2d game your VBOs or vertex array are going to be very small compared to 3d applications, so it's highly unlikely VBO will make any difference.

Comment: But wont this approach need frequent VBO switches?

Comment: Should I use float32 even for vertex coordinates?

Comment: You can minimize the number of VBO switches by combining several tiles into one VBO or one vertex array. Either way, for a 2d game you have a very low vertex count to notice any significant difference between VBOs and vertex arrays.
Float32 is the standard format for vertex coordinates and should be well optimized in drivers and hardware.